# Powershell - read separate sections of text file

Tags: file, parsing, powershell, text

I have a text file with two separate sections (example below).  I want to write a powershell cmdlet that will do something different for the machines in each section.  As always, thanks!

```
[Templates]
Computer1
Computer2

[Parents]
Computer3
Computer4
```

Answer (score 0):

this is something i have used in the past. you may be able to use it for your situation

```
$file = 'C:\temp\new 1.txt'
$contents = Get-Content $file | Out-String
$contents = [regex]::Split($contents, '\r\n\r\n')

$contents | ? {$_} | sort | % {
    write-host this is a section
    write-host $_
}
```

Comment: get-content automatically splits the file contents on carriage return line feeds resulting in an array, so it is piped to out-string so that all the lines are a single string object instead of an array of strings. then we split the whole thing on empty lines, which would be two carriage return line feeds, one right after the other (\r\n\r\n) so now we have an array of strings that are grouped into the sections you're looking for. the `? {$_}` part just filters out empty sections that had more than one blank line between them, and you can remove the sort if you don't want your sections sorted.